# DLL load failed while importing _core. Environment path using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, installation, path, dll

I am stuck trying to code a custom application with QGIS and Python. I have some Python knowledge but I am quite new to QGIS. I tried the intro of the cookbook: [Running Custom Applications](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications).

Now while I run the code from IDLE I constantly get an error message saying:

```
  File "H:\pathto\qgis_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from qgis.core import *
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _core: Cannot find module..
```

I guess this has to do with the environment path variables, I tried alot but can't seem to fix it. From another post out here I tried the sys.path paths, here's mine:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python\plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin\python37.zip
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qgis2web
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins
```

Currently I set these system variables in PYTHONPATH, and in Path:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\python
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\bin
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37
```

I'm not sure if these are correct, but this gives me the mentioned error. Now if I add:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\DLLs
```

to the PYTHONPATH(s), and try to open my script again in IDLE, it just does not open anymore.

Does anyone see the problem and how to fix this so I can run the script correctly?

Further notes:

- Before this I got some other errors, fixed some by installing PyQt, Python 3.8.2 (64bit) besides Python 3.7.2 (32bit) which I ran before.
- I haven't installed OSGeo4W separately, just QGIS3.10, not sure what that OSGeo4W is exactly, I'm just trying to get the Python part to work.

---

[image: PyQGIS errors]

I am still stuck. Here is an image where I tried different tests, in a OSGeo4W shell and a Windows shell, where I get different errors. As soon as I include a PATH the python shell won't even start anymore but without that path the shell doesn't seem to know where to search for the modules so I get errors every time.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the first steps of that tutorial using a OSGEO4W shell- I did:

```
set PYTHONPATH=c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\python
```

then

```
python
```

which gave:

```
    Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from qgis.core import *
    >>>
```

I don't have idle installed on that machine so I can't test it but I would try uninstalling and reinstalling QGIS and not changing the sys.path at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ian. I uninstalled QGIS, installed OSGeo4W and run the rules above in a cmd shell, but I still get the DLL error...

Comment: Did another test in the OSGeo4W shell like you said: when I first run py3_env en then python3, I get the python console to start but when I run the qgis.core command I get the error: "No module named qgis"